# how to put cursor at the beginning of `tab`

Tags: vim

When I open vim help, I press <kbd>0</kbd> to goto beginning of line;
When I press <kbd>j</kbd> to scroll down, the cursor jumps to right 8 spaces when focusing `tab`
And the cursor jumps back when focusing `non-tab`
It's not very good for eyes.
Is there an option to let vim focus the beginning of `tab` to let cursor stay at column 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting

```
set virtualedit=all
```

This lets you position the cursor anywhere in the buffer, even beyond the end of the line and before a tab character. In `help virtualedit` there is a warning that it might break some scripts or plugins, so use it carefully!

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

http://blog.killtheradio.net/how-tos/vim-cursor-at-beginning-of-tab-in-normal-mode/

```
set list lcs=tab:\ \ 
" Note the extra space after the second \
```

Comment: Good to know this tip. Thanks

Comment: This approach works for me... unless I want to have soft wrapping with breaks at words, which according to the wiki requires `set nolist`...